# How to access continuation token for ListBlobSegmented

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I am using ListBlobs Segemented but having problems with getting continuationTOken for next page.
Here is my code

```
 CloudBlobContainer container = GetContainerReference(fileType);
        BlobRequestOptions blobOptions = new BlobRequestOptions();

        ResultContinuation continuationToken=null;
        ResultSegment<IListBlobItem> blobs = container.ListBlobsSegmented(5000,continuationToken,blobOptions);
```

i never get HasMoreResults=true althought i know there are results ahead.and cannot access continuationToken. no idea which property where? i can see it in non public properties of ResultContinuationClass

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Where is the rest of your code which is trying to check the continuation token?  The following code works:

```
    BlobRequestOptions options = new BlobRequestOptions();
    options.UseFlatBlobListing = true;
    ResultSegment<IListBlobItem> list = Global.ContainerTools.ListBlobsSegmented(5, null, options);

    foreach (CloudBlob b in list.Results)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(b.Uri);
    }

    while (list.ContinuationToken != null)
    {
        list = Global.ContainerTools.ListBlobsSegmented(5, list.ContinuationToken, options);
        foreach (CloudBlob b in list.Results)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(b.Uri);
        }
    }
```